# Custom HandlerWrapper with MonologBundle

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I am using Symfony 3.1 and I try to configure Monolog in such a way, that requests from the Googlebot are not logged. For this I wrote a `UserAgentProcessor`which already works as intended. In the next step I tried to write BotFilter which looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Handler;

use Monolog\Handler\HandlerWrapper;

class FilterBotsHandler extends HandlerWrapper
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isHandling(array $record)
    {
        if (stripos($record['extra']['userAgent'], 'bot') !== false){
            return false;
        } else {
            return $this->handler->isHandling($record);
        }
    }
}
```

This was inspired by the comments in the `HandlerWrapper` abstract class (take a look [here](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/HandlerWrapper.php)).

Now I want to add that filter to my monolog yml-configuration. I tried adding it to my services but this was not possible as `HandlerWrapper` needs a Handler instance for its constructor. I researched how I could use the filter without a service but as far as I can see, the monolog bundle only accepts built-in types and the generic service type.

Now the question is: How can I use the filter in my configuration?

Comment: You want to move the expression to the config? Defined in the monolog config isn't the correct location, you could create a service (that monolog uses) and inject expressions via the parameters: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html

Comment: I don' think you understood my question correctly. What I basically want is to be able to set a `handler` that will be called by my `FilterBotsHandler`.
Take a look at the [DeduplcationHandler](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/DeduplicationHandler.php) for instance. You can specify another `Handler`here, which will be called by the `DeduplicationHandler`. I try to do the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am using Symfony 3.1 and I try to configure Monolog in such a way, that requests from the GoogleBot are not logged...

---

1. The quick way to prevent robots visiting your site is put these two lines into the `/robots.txt` file on your server. Create a `robots.txt` file in 'web' directory and paste the follows content:

   ```
   User-agent: *
   Disallow: /
   ```

   > https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en&visit_id=1-636097099675465769-3677253464&rd=1

   **It's the recommended option when you need avoid access *fully*, meaning your sites will not longer be index by search engines and other bots. You don't need to configure/implement anything in your application to achieve it.**

---

2. Now, if you need the bot to enter, but you don't want register it in logs. Instead of writing log files somewhere, *some* handlers are used to filter or modify log entries before sending them to *other* handlers. One powerful, built-in handler called `fingers_crossed` is used in the `prod` environment by default. It stores all log messages during a request but only passes them to a second handler if one of the messages reaches an `action_level`:

   ```
   # app/config/config.yml
   monolog:
       handlers:
           filter_for_errors:
               type: fingers_crossed
               # if *one* log is error or higher, pass *all* to file_log
               action_level: error
               handler: file_log

           # now passed *all* logs, but only if one log is error or higher
           file_log:
               type: stream
               path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
   ```

   Thus, in your `prod.log` file just will register the messages/requests that contains some error, so the *bots* don't have effect in this level.

   More details about this http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html

---

3. What you try to do is not advisable, because the *handler* will depend from http request instead of log records, which will be out of context, however you can register its own *handler* in Symfony easily:

   Let's create the custom handler class:

   ```
   namespace AppBundle\Monolog\Handler;

   use Monolog\Handler\AbstractHandler;

   class StopBotLogHandler extends AbstractHandler
   {
       public function isBotRequestDetected()
       {
           // here your code to detect Bot requests, return true or false
           // something like this: 
           // return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && preg_match('/bot|crawl|slurp|spider/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
       }

       /**
        * Checks whether the given record will be handled by this handler.
        *
        * This is mostly done for performance reasons, to avoid calling processors for nothing.
        *
        * Handlers should still check the record levels within handle(), returning false in isHandling()
        * is no guarantee that handle() will not be called, and isHandling() might not be called
        * for a given record.
        *
        * @param array $record Partial log record containing only a level key (e.g: array('level' => 100) for DEBUG level)
        *
        * @return bool
        */
       public function isHandling(array $record)
       {
           return $this->isBotRequestDetected();
       }

       /**
        * Handles a record.
        *
        * All records may be passed to this method, and the handler should discard
        * those that it does not want to handle.
        *
        * The return value of this function controls the bubbling process of the handler stack.
        * Unless the bubbling is interrupted (by returning true), the Logger class will keep on
        * calling further handlers in the stack with a given log record.
        *
        * @param array $record The record to handle
        *
        * @return bool true means that this handler handled the record, and that bubbling is not permitted.
        *              false means the record was either not processed or that this handler allows bubbling.
        */
       public function handle(array $record)
       {
           // do nothing, just returns true whether the request is detected as "bot", this will break the handlers loop.
           //             else returns false and other handler will handle the record.

           return $this->isBotRequestDetected();
       }
   }
   ```

   Whenever you add a record to the logger, it traverses the handler stack. Each handler decides whether it fully handled the record, and if so, the propagation of the record ends there.

   **Important:** Read the phpdoc from `isHandling()` and `handle()` methods for more details.

   Next, let's register the class as service "without tags":

   ```
   # app/config/services.yml
   services:
       monolog.handler.stop_bot_log:
           class: AppBundle\Monolog\Handler\StopBotLogHandler
           public: false
   ```

   Then, add its *handler* to `handlers` list:

   ```
   # app/config/config_prod.yml
   monolog:
       handlers:
           # ...

           stopbotlog:
               type: service
               id: monolog.handler.stop_bot_log
               priority: 1
   ```

   Note the `type` property must be equal to `service`, `id` must be the service name before defined and `priority` must be greater than `0` to ensure that its *handler* will be executed before that any other handler.

   When the *GoogleBot* performs a request to website application the `stopbotlog` *handler* stops all *handlers* after him and don't register any log message.

   **Remember it's not the recommended way to do that! According to your needs, implementing option 1 or 2 should be enough.**

---

If you want ignore bot requests for handlers group, you can override the `monolog.handler.group.class` container parameter and override the group `handler` behavior:

```
namespace AppBundle\Handler;

use Monolog\Handler\GroupHandler;

class NoBotGroupHandler extends GroupHandler
{
    public function isBotRequestDetected()
    {
        // here your code to detect Bot requests, return true or false
    }

    public function handle(array $record)
    {
        if ($this->isBotRequestDetected()) {
            // ignore bot request for handlers list
            return false === $this->bubble;
        }

        return parent::handle($record);
    }
}
```

in your `config_prod.yml` or `services.yml`:

```
parameters:
    monolog.handler.group.class: AppBundle\Handler\NoBotGroupHandler
```

That's it! Now, you can stop bot logs for custom handles list:

```
# config_prod.yml
monolog:
    handlers:
        grouped:
            type: group
            members: [main, console, chromephp]
```

---

Finally, if you have difficulty to analyze your logs files I recommend using this amazing tool: https://github.com/EasyCorp/easy-log-handler

Comment: Thank you very much for this extensive answer! I am well aware of 1) and 2). In fact I'm using 2) at the moment to only log levels `error` and worse.
I don't want to use 1) as I actually want the bots to scan the page. I now implemented 3) as suggested. Unlike you mentioned, I don't have to rely on anything but the record, as I have added the userAgent to the record with the help of a processor. 

I have one remaining question: Can your solution somehow be used together with the group handler, such that only one group will be blocked?

Comment: Yes, you can create the custom handler from `GroupHandler` and apply the same logic to `handlers` list.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this results in the same problem as described in my initial question: The `GroupHandler` receives other `handlers` as constructor parameters, and thus cannot be used as a service.

Comment: For option 3, make sure to use different aliases: using `monolog.handler.stop_bot_log` in `services.yaml` and `monolog` > `handlers` > `stop_bot_log` in `monolog.yaml` will result in a circular reference.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a dirty trick, but if you really need it, you may make it like this.

Supposing you want to wrap a handler with a type `stream`:

Add a constructor in you **FilterBotsHandler**:

```
public function __constructor($path, $level, $bubble, $permissions) {
    $this->handler = new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($path, $level, $bubble, $permissions);
}
```

And then redefine a parameter `monolog.handler.stream.class`:

```
parameters:
    monolog.handler.stream.class:   AppBundle\Handler\FilterBotsHandler
```

Make sure that this parameter will be defined **after** it was defined by MonologBundle.

That's it. Should work.

Answer (score 0):

You may write `CompilerPass` in your `AppBundle` which adds [configurator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/configurators.html) to `monolog` service. Such configurator can be also a [request event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#request-events-checking-types) which can replace all handlers dynamically on request and bot detection and push empty handlers array to `Logger` which can be hold on configurator call.

In other words configurator added to DI by `CompilerPass` and added to `EventDispatcher` as `Listener` to `Kernel` events which `onRequest` check `User-Agent` header looking for bot and then clears `Monolog\Logger` (passed in configurator) all handlers (or putting an `NullHandler` if empty handlers array fails).

DI configurator is only way to change your services during runtime which can be applied as service definition level. Such definition can be attached or detached if not needed and it doesn't really change anything in your application.